# mysql.jdbc exception outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, int

I am running into an error when I am trying to access the contents of database (`BIGINT`) from a Java file. I am not able to figure out the fix for this exception.

**I am getting following error:**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException:
    '5.62949953421312E15' in column '1' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER.
```

**Java code:**

```
long  pID=0;

SQLStatement = connection.createStatement();
String Query101 = "select projectID from Project";
ResultSet rs101 = SQLStatement.executeQuery(Query101);
while (rs101.next()) {
    pID = rs101.getLong("ProjectId");
}
```

**SQL code:**

```
CREATE TABLE Project (projectID bigint(20) Primary key)
```

The value for `projectID` in the database table I am using is `5629499534213120`.

Comment: Can I know why I am given -1? Please give some explanation

Comment: The signed range for `long` in Java and `BIGINT` in MySQL are both -2^63 to 2^63 - 1. Your issue is on the MySQL side of things, hence the `MySQLDataException`.

Comment: Any headway on this issue?

Comment: Actually I have just changed the value to varchar and convert it to long on java end and now it is working fine. From my research it looked like a bug in mysql. BIGINT to long conversion.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a source or two of this bug from your research? I typically use Connector/Net, but you never know when a Java project will pop up. Thanks!

Comment: @DerekW: there were couple of places https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=239274

Answer (score 2):

your pID is long type, which is 4 bytes, max value is 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647.
So you cannot assign 5.62949953421312E15 to it at  pID = rs101.getLong("ProjectId");

Comment: Long is 64 bit. It is 2^64-1 so I think it should work. 32 bit is for int values. Here is link for that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: In `C#` the `long` type is 64 bits (8 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

After looking [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) over and checking out if there is any known MySQL Connector/J issue. I believe that your **ProjectID** column is actually an INT (synonym of INTEGER) as the exception suggests. I would look over your **Project** table and ensure that the column is really a BIGINT.

`BIGINT` is MySQL's 64-bit signed integer, just like `long` is Java's 64-bit signed integer. Meaning they share the same range of -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup> - 1.

You are using the correct approach. But I think your column's datatype is not what you think it is.

Comment: Table is definitely BIGINT.  (Rather if I make the SQL table value as int the code works perfectly)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why the exception would label the column as an `INTEGER` type.

Answer (score 0):

If you encapsulate this table, you can see whether the transfer type is long when you execute the set operation

like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5zyV.png)

I was here that did not turn the type to cause this problem